# Primefaces file upload not accepting charset as UTF-8

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, utf-8

When the file is uploaded with Chinese Text as file name, it changes to some weird text on completion of upload. I have tried below possible solutions too but no help.

1. Setting HTML form accept charset attribute:

   ```
   <h:form accept-charset="UTF-8" />
   ```
2. Adding the below character Encoding Filter in web.xml before Primefaces file Upload filter and adding the following entry to  of the /WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml file

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

glassfish-web.xml:

```
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
```

3. Setting HTML meta tag:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   ```

Using Primefaces 6.0.19

Can someone please help on this issue ?

Comment: Anyone can please provide help on it ? I have been struggling with this for days now.